# Azure Authentication: Only allow users with MFA enabled

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a web application which is currently configured to require a login using Azure.  Azure also lets you configure MFA on a user-by-user level.  What I would like to do is only allow a login attempt to be successful if the user has MFA enforced.  Can anyone point me towards a good resource.  I'm sure I'm not the first person who has wanted to do this but can't find any information on making it happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the `amr` (authentication method) claim.  If a user authenticated with MFA then the claim will contain the value `mfa`.  If they only authenticated with username/password then the value will be `pwd`.

More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-token-and-claims/).

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need an Azure AD Premium subscription to enable MFA. See [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication-get-started/) to get started and see [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication/) for more info.

Comment: This doesn't really address my question.  I already have MFA enabled.  What I want to do is limit my site so that it only allows users that have MFA enabled without enabling MFA for my entire directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure the **Authentication/Authorization** of the web app.

   [image]

   [image]
2. Since you have MFA enabled, I assume that the users in your AD are also MFA-enabled, which means when you create the user you checked the **"Enable Multi-Factor Authentication"** check box.

   [image]
3. Choose **"your directory"->Applications Tab->Add** to add the web application which require a MFA login.

   [image]
4. Double click the web application you added in step 2,  **configure Tab->user assignment required to access app->save**, enable the user assignment required.

   [image]
5. Assign users. Under **users** tab, choose the users you want to assign authority, then click **assign** at the bottom. When this completed, the column **Assigned**  in the user table will be Yes.

   [image]

Comment: I believe some of these settings are only available if you are using Azure AD Premium which we are not using.  Thanks though.  I think BenV found an answer I can use.

Comment: Glad you found the answer. I'll check BenV's too.